# Proptypes isRequired undefined

Tags: reactjs

I'm learning reactjs and i want to use PropTypes, in some examples i have seen someting like `PropTypes.string.isRequired`. But if i write this i get an error that isRequired is undefined.

```
    import React from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-type";
import classnames from "classnames";

const TextFieldGroup = ({ field, value, label, error, type, onChange }) => {
  return (
    <div className={classnames("form-group", { "has-error": error })}>
      <label className="control-label">{label}</label>
      <input
        value={value}
        onChange={onChange}
        type={type}
        name={field}
        className="form-control"
      />
      {error && <span className="help-block">{error}</span>}
    </div>
  );
};

TextFieldGroup.propTypes = {
  field: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  value: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  label: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  error: PropTypes.string,
  type: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  onChange: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  checkUserExists: PropTypes.func.isRequired
};

TextFieldGroup.defaultProps = {
  type: "text"
};

export default TextFieldGroup;
```

I hope someone can help, thanks!

Comment: Whats the actual error you're getting?

Comment: TypeError: Cannot read property 'isRequired' of undefined

Comment: You are importing wrong package its prop-types not prop-type

Comment: import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

Comment: Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It’s prop-types but not prop-type. You are importing prop-type but not prop-types. The right module is prop-types

So You need to install

```
  npm i —save prop-types
```

Then import it like

```
 import PropTypes from "prop-types"
```

Comment: I didn't downvote you, but it may be because your import is also incorrect (same as OP).

Comment: Thanks. It’s Typo error I typed in my mobile so missed s at the end